# /bin/sh privilege escalation code using a fake ls - why does this work?

Tags: linux, shell, security, sh

I recently came across this snippet on the following site:

https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/writing-secure-shell-scripts

Here's the script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$USER" = "root" ] ; then
  /bin/cp /bin/sh /tmp/.secretshell
  /bin/chown root /tmp/.secretshell
  /bin/chmod 4666 root /tmp/.secretshell
fi

exec /bin/ls $*
```

Let's assume that the person who runs this code has low-level access to the system (i.e. they can write to `/tmp/`), and that the system is not 'hardened'.

In the link above, the author of the code says that, "This simple little script has created a shell that always grants its user root access to the Linux system."

The idea is that the attacker would write the script above, name it `ls`, and drop it in the `/tmp/` directory on the system. Any user running `ls` (rather than `/bin/ls`) in `/tmp/` will therefore inadvertently run this script. If the user running `ls` happens to be `root`, he/she will trigger the (malicious) code in the enclosing `if/fi` block. To conceal that anything harmful has happened, the directory listing that the user wants will still execute as expected due to the final `exec /bin/ls $*` line.

What I don't quite understand is what the final line of the `if/fi` block is doing. This is how I interpret the first two lines of the `if/fi` block:

In the line `/bin/cp /bin/sh /tmp/.secretshell`, the script copies the `/bin/sh` binary to `/tmp/`, renaming it to `.secretshell`, a hidden file. OK fine.

In the line `/bin/chown root /tmp/.secretshell`, the script changes the owner of `.secretshell` to `root`. OK fine.

What I don't quite understand is the line `/bin/chmod 4666 root /tmp/.secretshell`. As far as I know, I think this line is meant to flip the `setuid` bit for `.secretshell`, so that every time `.secretshell` is run, it is run as its owner (now `root`). This would (I suppose) give anyone running `.secretshell` the ability to run `sh` as `root`. But there are two things here which seem problematic:

1) How can `root` be inserted as the second argument to `/bin/chmod`, when `chmod` is expecting a directory or file name after the permissions argument?

2) Doesn't the `*666` part of the permissions argument make `.secretshell` *non-executable* by converting its permissions mask to `-rwSrw-rw-`? If the intent is to *execute* `.secretshell`, how can this be desirable?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article contains several mistakes and fundamental misunderstandings about shell scripting:

1. You're right about the extra `root`, this is probably a copy-paste error.
2. You're right about the lack of executable permissions. The author did not test their own code.
3. The whole  approach fails on non-Debian based systems like CentOS or macOS where `sh` is `bash`, because bash drops suid.
4. The author claims that `ls -l $name` where `name='. ; /bin/rm -Rf /'` will execute the `rm`. This is false.
5. The author further appears to claim that `ls -l "$name"` where `` name='. `/bin/rm -Rf /`' `` will execute the command. This is also false.

I would suggest taking the whole article with a grain of salt.

Comment: #3 can be avoided with `/tmp/.secretshell -p`

Comment: 6. The article assumes that root has `.` in its `PATH` (and earlier in it than `/bin`).  That would be atypical, especially for root, and it is poor practice for anyone exactly because it can result in executing a different program than you meant to do.